# How to compare value or keys in the hash table?

Tags: java

Suppose I have code

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
    Hashtable ht2 = new Hashtable();
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        ht.put(i, new Integer (i));
    }
    for(int i=50;i<100;i++)
    {
        ht2.put(i, new Integer (i));
    }
}
```

If I wanted to compare the two different hashtable, how would I go about to do this in Java? EDIT: if I wanted to compare key or the actual value in the hashtable

Comment: Do you want to determine if the entire hash tables are equal?

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"?  Can you give an example?

Comment: Also use `HashMap` instead if you can.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough. I want to compare a key or value inside them. if ht has key 1,2,3,4,5 and ht2 has key 4,5,6,7,8 How would i go about and know they both have 4,5 same key. Same goes for value. What if ht has key 1,2,3,4,5 with value 1,2,3,4,5 where ht2 has key 6,7,8,9,0 with value 4,5,6,7,8. In this case, we have different key but same value of 4 and 5

Comment: So, are you are looking to determine which keys and values overlap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will print out all common key/value pairs:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Map<Integer, Integer> ht = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    Map<Integer, Integer> ht2 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        ht.put(i, i);
    }
    for(int i=50;i<100;i++)
    {
        ht2.put(i, i);
    }

    System.out.println("The following keys and values match:");

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> htEntries : ht.entrySet()) {
        if(ht2.containsKey(htEntries.getKey()) && ht2.get(htEntries.getKey()).equals(htEntries.getValue())){
            System.out.println("\tKey: " + htEntries.getKey() + " Value: " + htEntries.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is very helpful! Can you elaborate on how the last for loop works if possible? Thank you again!

Comment: It just compares all Map entries (key/value pair) between ht and ht2.  Worth noting, this is similar to Louis Wasserman's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out which key-value combinations they have in common, use something like

```
 HashSet<Entry<Integer, Integer>> entries = new HashSet<Entry<Integer, Integer>>(
   table1.entrySet());
 entries.retainAll(table2.entrySet());
```

and `entries` will have only the entries with the same keys and values from both maps.

Alternately, FYI, Guava provides [`Maps.difference`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#difference%28java.util.Map,%20java.util.Map%29), which lets you pick out the entries in common, entries with different values but the same keys, and the entries with keys that aren't in the other map, all at once.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare that the two mapping are identical, use `ht.equals(ht2)`.

To compare just the keys, use `ht.keySet().equals(ht2.keySet())`.

Comparing the values is a little trickier, and depends on your requirements. What exactly are your requirements?

P.S. `Hashtable` is obsolete; `HashMap<Integer,Integer>` should be preferred in most circumstances.